# React Native TextInput -- How to differentiate between onFocus from a tap vs onSubmitEditing?

Tags: react-native, textinput, onfocus

Is there a way to tell if a `<TextInput>`'s `onFocus` method was fired because it was directly tapped on vs. if it was focused on via another `<TextInput>`'s `onSubmitEnding` method?

**Example**

*Disclaimer*: I know it's bad practice to use strings as refs, but it makes this example simpler

```
<TextInput
    ref='Text1'
    onSubmitEnding={() => this.refs.Text2.focus()}
/>

<TextInput
    ref='Text2'
    onFocus={() => console.log('Fire only on tap')}
/>
```

If I tap directly on `Text2`, 'Fire only on tap' is logged as expected. However, if I'm focused on `Text1` and tap its return button to shift focus to `Text2`, the statement will also be logged, which is not the behavior I'd like to have (in this example).

How can we differentiate between direct taps and focus via `onSubmitEnding`? Thanks!